# How to group a Series by values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, series

I currently have a pandas `Series` with dtype `Timestamp`, and I want to group it by date (and have many rows with different times in each group).

The seemingly obvious way of doing this would be something similar to

```
grouped = s.groupby(lambda x: x.date())
```

However, pandas' `groupby` groups Series by its index. How can I make it group by value instead?

Comment: IIUC doesn't `grouped = s.groupby(s.dt.date)` work? what are you trying to achieve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929426/groupby-for-pandas-series-not-working

Answer (score 142):

```
grouped = s.groupby(s)
```

Or:

```
grouped = s.groupby(lambda x: s[x])
```

Comment: Is it me, or is it a little ridiculous that `s.groupby()` doesn't work?

Comment: you are right tough Python was not invented for doing groupby in data science XD

Comment: For `ts.cumsum().groupby(ts.cumsum()).count()` , It is better to have a chain method or I have to calculate twice without a variable

Comment: It doesn't work for me: it just says: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x000002AD0136A1F0>

Answer (score 12):

Three methods:

DataFrame: `pd.groupby(['column']).size()`

Series： `sel.groupby(sel).size()`

Series to DataFrame:

`pd.DataFrame( sel, columns=['column']).groupby(['column']).size()`

Comment: What is `sel` ?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant it's the name of a `Series` object

Answer (score 12):

For anyone else who wants to do this inline without throwing a lambda in (which tends to kill performance):

```
s.to_frame(0).groupby(0)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should convert it to a DataFrame, then add a column that is the date().  You can do groupby on the DataFrame with the date column.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(s, columns=["datetime"])
df["date"] = df["datetime"].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df.groupby("date")
```

Then "date" becomes your index.  You have to do it this way because the final grouped object needs an index so you can do things like [select a group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#selecting-a-group).

Answer (score 1):

To add another suggestion, I often use the following as it uses simple logic:

```
pd.Series(index=s.values).groupby(level=0)
```

Comment: This works on index values, not on the values themselves. You would get groups that share a common index value (for example same date if that is your index).

Comment: Look at it more closely, or try it, and you'll see that it works on the values themselves because I do index=s.values. You would be right if I had done `pd.Series(s.values).groupby(level=0)`

Comment: Yes, I looked at it again and I misread the first time, for which I apologize.