# Groupby and max for a series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to obtain the maximum of each group in a Series:

`return a`

```
0
0    0.071429
0    0.071429
1    0.083333
1    0.333333
1    0.333333
1    0.083333
3    0.058824
3    0.058824
Name: 1, dtype: float64`
```

Inspired by [How to group a Series by values in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483670/how-to-group-a-series-by-values-in-pandas), I try:

```
b = a.groupby(a).max()
return b
```

But I lose the names of the original index values 0, 1 and 3, and oddly enough, they aren't even replaced by max values found.

```
1
0.058824    0.058824
0.071429    0.071429
0.083333    0.083333
0.333333    0.333333
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to get the maximums, and keep the index values after the groupby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the Series' index, rather than the Series itself, as the argument to `groupby`:

`a.groupby(a.index).max()`