# Grouping by Pandas Series Values using Grouper in Python

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas Series with Timestamps that I want to group by month and count. If this data was in a DataFrame, I would use a Grouper like this:

```
data = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01"), pd.Timestamp("2020-01-05"), pd.Timestamp("2020-02-05")])
data.name = "mydata"

data.to_frame().groupby(pd.Grouper(key=data.name, freq="MS")).size()

> mydata
> 2020-01-01    2
> 2020-02-01    1
> Freq: MS, dtype: int64
```

However, if I try to perform the groupby directly on the Series, it tries to group by the index rather than the values in the Series:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS")).size()

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

This question describes how to group by the value: [How to group a Series by values in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33483670/2522041), but I don't understand how that answer can be applied to using a Grouper. Trying to set the `key` in the Grouper doesn't seem to work:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=data, freq="MS")).size()

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I set the index to the values in the series, the grouper works:

```
data.index = data
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS")).size()
```

Although this works, I suspect there's a better way to perform a Grouper based groupby operation on the values in a Pandas Series. Any thoughts on how to perform this operation? Thanks!

Comment: Does you data have to be in a series?

Comment: `data = pd.Series(vals, index = vals)` where `vals` is the list of timestamps allows you to essentially do `data.index=data` directly in the constructor. Not sure that is any better though.

Comment: That’s a good idea but unfortunately the Series constructor section was just part of the example data I made for this post. I suppose there’s always the option of turning the Series into a DataFrame before grouping. But I was hoping to group directly on the Series since it’s something that intuitively feels like it should be possible. If not - then maybe that’s a feature request for the Pandas team!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know about possibility how to use `pd.Grouper` directly in such case. You have to either set the index (as you already mentioned in the question) or you have to make a DataFrame from Series. If you do not insist on using Grouper object you could also use `.dt` accessor for datetime grouping like the following:

```
data.groupby(data.dt.month).size()
```

or you could use `strftime` (but it's a bit slower)

```
data.groupby(data.dt.strftime("%Y-%m")).size()
```

These are the only cases I was able to come up where you can use your series directly but I understand that this might not be what you wanted.